# GNU Screen: hardstatus truncates color and text whenever terminal window width is small

Tags: gnu-screen

My GNU Screen hardstatus:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline '%{= kG}%{C}%S: %{c}%{= kG}|%= %{= kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}'
```

Normally looks like this:

[image: hardstatus OK]

However, whenever I resize my terminal emulator window by reducing its total width, eventually my hardstatus line starts to look like this:

[image: hardstatus weird]

It somehow gets confused and truncates / clobbers the color and the text.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have an odd number of `%?`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. If you want promote your comment to an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.